# Exception of Unauthorized while using MostRecentlyUsedList in metro apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am working with Store apps using C#.
I am using `StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList` to load Local Epub files.
After getting those file as a Storage file.

```
string EpubPathToken= Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.Add(file);
StorageFile file = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(EpubPathToken);
Extraction(file);
```

While Extracting the Epub file as Zip to Package folder using `ApplicationData` I am getting an **Exeption of Unauthorized.**

[Here's screen shot of error](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=cf76631f8b2afa1e&id=CF76631F8B2AFA1E%21131&sff=1&authkey=!ABwX83pGKWsN_8M)

Why because If I use the same code using from KnownFolders like Pictures Library the Extraction is working Fine.

Can any one give me any idea about this ?

Comment: Are you getting error while extraction or copying file to `ApplicationData` ?

Comment: While Extracting the Zip file. I am using `ZipArchive`.
This is I am getting the file.
`Stream zipMemoryStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();`
//file is the name which I am working with

Comment: Try [my code for unzipping the files](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/515704/Archive-Multiple-Files-In-Zip-Extract-Zip-Archive). you need to add `EPUB` file format in picker line.

Comment: @Xyroid May I know what is `storeFile` & `zipfile` in Your code.
I think `zipfile` is a Storagefile.
Here is my code which I am using for Extracting zip file. 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215679/exception-on-extracting-the-zip-file-in-c-sharp/17290280#17290280 ]

Comment: `storeFile` is a list of `StorageFile` to create zip file. `zipFile` is the resultant `StorageFile` after zipping. You can also [download](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/515704/ZipArchive.zip) the sample.

Comment: Ok, Using your Code I Completed my extraction of Epub file. But some times It is giving Exception of `'System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.
But if I use that file using any Epub Reader It is working fine. It is not an Issue. I wiil go through the file & I will fix my problem.

Apart from this, I have two doubts on store apps.
A) I have Storagefile value in one .cs page I want to use that value in another .cs page
I amusing with `this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(..` not working
Can U give me idea about this.

Comment: B) How to check the folder with same name is exist or not in the another folder.

I don't want ask as another question.
Please give me your suggestion as answer.
Thanks

Comment: @Xyroid Can You give me the suggetion for what I am asked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue of getting exception of **Unauthorized** With the use of [Blog](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/515704/Archive-Multiple-Files-In-Zip-Extract-Zip-Archive)

I changed the code snippet according to my requirement.

> The source of code describes writes bytes of file in `ZipArchiveEntry`,
>       hence I used a helper method `GetByteFromFile()`, which takes  `StorageFile` object and returns me `byte[]` array.

Finally thanks to [Xyroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1230188/xyroid)