# How to enable button if item selected in a GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, microsoft-metro

I want to enable button when a grid view item is selected so that i will update my GUI in metro apps. The button is also include as a list view item. Below is the code snippet of what i want to do. Please help.

```
<GridView Name="searchPanelGrid"  SelectionMode="Single" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="True"
                                ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled ="True"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionItems}}" Grid.Row="2">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="6" Height="175" Width="150" Background="#FFFAFAFA">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="85"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Background="#FF0A56BF" Width="150" Height="85" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=ThumnailUrl}" Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=VideoName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF017DD5" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" FontSize="12"/>
                    <Button x:Name="downloadButton" Grid.Row="3" Content="Download Video" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{StaticResource DownloadButtonStyle}" Click="downloadButton_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Unable to bind button property IsEnabled. Any suggestion how i do this ??

Comment: I'm not sure how much it helps U.

`GridView.GotFocus += GridView_GotFocus;
GridView.LostFocus += GridView_LostFocus;
 void GridView_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button.Opacity = 0.5;
        }`

Comment: I have solve this by declaring a property in my Class by which collectionitems is bind and bind that property to button isenabled property and then on SelectionChangeEvent i get selected item of grid view and set button isenabled property value to true. Its working. Any how thanks for help.

Comment: Glad You got it..
A request as a Stackoverflow user, what ever the answer you got for question try to post reply as a answer with simple description or weblink which helps you ,
It gives help to who will see your question next time as a reference.
like this
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289853/exception-of-unauthorized-while-using-mostrecentlyusedlist-in-metro-apps/17335074#17335074 ]

Comment: @Kumar updated as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solve this by declaring a property in my Class by which collectionitems is bind and bind that property to button isenabled property and then on SelectionChangeEvent i get selected item of grid view and set button isenabled property value to true. Its working.

Xaml file SearchPanel.xaml

```
<GridView Name="searchPanelGrid"  SelectionMode="Single" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="True"
                                ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled ="True"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionItems}}" Grid.Row="2" SelectionChanged="searchPanelGrid_SelectionChanged">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="6" Height="175" Width="150" Background="#FFFAFAFA">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="85"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Background="#FF0A56BF" Width="150" Height="85" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=ThumnailUrl}" Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=VideoName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF017DD5" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" FontSize="12"/>
                    <Button x:Name="downloadButton" Grid.Row="3" Content="Download Video" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{StaticResource DownloadButtonStyle}" Click="downloadButton_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Class that is bind to ItemsSource propertry of GridView

```
public class VideoInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            isSelected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    private string thumnailUrl;
    public string ThumnailUrl
    {
        get { return thumnailUrl; }
        set
        {
            thumnailUrl = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ThumnailUrl");
        }
    }

    private string videoName;
    public string VideoName
    {
        get { return videoName; }
        set
        {
            videoName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("VideoName");

        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

.cs file SearchPanel.xaml.cs on SelectionChangeEvent of GridView

```
private void searchPanelGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MovieInfo info = (e.AddedItems[0]) as MovieInfo;
        info.IsSelected = true;
    }
```